# parse json based on dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a json that I'd like to parse based on the 'zone' field in order to get a list of region etc through a select input.

```
var data = {
    "zone01": [{
        "region": "North",
        "state": "New York",
        "county": "Albany",
        "code": "01"
    }, {
        "region": "North",
        "state": "New York",
        "county": "Albany",
        "code": "05"
    }, {
        "region": "North",
        "state": "Maine",
        "county": "Auburn",
        "code": "07"
    }],
    "zone02": [{
        "region": "South",
        "state": "Florida",
        "county": "Gainseville",
        "code": "82"
    }, {
        "region": "South",
        "state": "Florida",
        "county": "Macclenny",
        "code": "73"
    }]
};
```

I can parse it by using:

```
function setValues(range, zone, region, state, country){
    if(range === 'zone'){
        var getRegions = _.groupBy(data.zone02, 'region');
        $.each(getRegions, function(k, v){
            var region = JSON.stringify(k);
            region = region.replace(/"/g,'');
            $('select#region').append('<option value="'+region+'">'+region+'</option>');
        });
    }
}
```

But what I really need is _.groupBy(data.zone02, 'region') with data.zone02 being data + the function's variable **zone**

**UPDATE**

Here's my finished product, sans readability and re-usability: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/8mR4n/9/)

Comment: Do you mean `var getRegions = _.groupBy(data[zone], 'region');` ?

Comment: yes - but don't tell anyone.  I tried it before and it said no but I think I may have put quotes in self['blush']

Comment: This isn't parsing JSON, it's just accessing a property in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation to reference a property using a variable.

```
data[zone]
```